# .Net Core 3.1 WebAPI How to serialize IEnumerable<T> from POST body

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have method in controller:

```
[HttpPost("add")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]IEnumerable<TrainingModel> model)
```

I have model `TrainingModel`:

```
public class TrainingModel
    {
        public int TrainingId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public float Distance { get; set; }
        public int ElapsedTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string MapPolyline { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
    }
```

Next query returning empty object using Postman
[image]

[image]
Could anybody help? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Was not able to reproduce it in new solution(TBH with a little bit different data). Provided code seems to be fine.

Comment: Did you check for model-errors?

Comment: this code works for me! can you share the json body.

Comment: Same code and same request data works on my side. Did you do some custom operations on the model binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was a problem with `TrainingId` property, given value for this property caused an overflow. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issue. For me it was because for some reason the model I was trying to deserialize into did not contain [DataContract] [DataMember] attributes. Once I added those in everything deserialized as expected:

```
[DataContract]
public class PersonViewModel
{
        [DataMember(Name = "address", EmitDefaultValue = true)]
        public string Address { get; set; }
}
```